# Slider js по 4кнопкам

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

У меня есть Слайдер на Js там 4картинки и 2кнопки вправо влево и 4круглых кнопок. Задача заключается в том чтобы можно было менять картинки по круглым кнопкам. То есть активна 1картинка(1кнопка)Если нажать на 3кругулю кнопку, должна появится 3картинка. Думаю понятно обьяснил.

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>простой слайдер</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1></h1>

        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slider-line">
                <img src="./images/elephant.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/gorilla.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/home.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/ice_cream.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="slider-prev">Prev</button>
        <button class="slider-next">Next</button>

        <label for="radio1">1</label>
        <label for="radio2">2</label>
        <label for="radio3">3</label>
        <label for="radio4">4</label>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}

html, body {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 30px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

button {
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: .9rem;
}

button:hover {
    background: orangered;
}

button:active {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.courses {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.courses li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.courses a {
    color: #222;
}

.slider {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    margin: 20px auto;

}

.slider-line {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 256px;
    display: flex;
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
label{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
    let offset = 0;
const sliderLine = document.querySelector('.slider-line');

document.querySelector('.slider-next').addEventListener('click', function(){
    offset = offset + 256;
    if (offset > 768) {
        offset = 0;
    }
    sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
});

document.querySelector('.slider-prev').addEventListener('click', function () {
    offset = offset - 256;
    if (offset < 0) {
        offset = 768;
    }
    sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
});
```

Comment: Lable присвойте такой же класс как и кнопок влево, вправо

Comment: @Arcadiy а смысл? Lable 4 ,а кнопке 2(влево вправо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы на вашем месте немного изменил логику кнопок:
во-первых нужно задать счетчик слайдеров:

```
let  currentSlider = 0;
```

и фукнкцию, которая меняет слайдер:

```
function toggleSlider (count) {
    if (count < 0) {
       currentSlider = 3
    }

    if (count > 3) {
       currentSlider = 0
    }

    const offset = currentSlider * 256;
    sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
});
```

Теперь при нажатии на кнопку вперед/назад достаточно вызвать данную функцию и передать в нее номер нового слайдера:

- на следующий слайдер toggleSlider(currentSlider++)
- на предыдущий toggleSlider(currentSlider--)

Теперь и проблема с пагинацией решена:

Получите список из 4 круглых кнопок, перебирайте их и навести на каждую функцию - toggleSlider, передав в нее в качестве аргумента - номер кнопки.
Должно заработать

Comment: Вроде бы понял. Спасибо

Comment: при клике на кнопку передавать в функцию currentSlider++ ?

Comment: При клике на кнопку next - да, передавайте номер текущего слайда, увеличенный на 1

Comment: Когда дохожу до зелёной машинке и нажимаю next слайдер перемещается и показывает белый фон
также со слоном, если назад то слайдер покажет белый фон

Comment: К сожалению, не знаю где у вас какая картинка))), но попробуйте использовать вместо currentSlider++/currentSlider--  такой синтаксис: ++currentSlider/--currentSlider

Comment: сделал одно условие ,а в это условие поместил ваш код.Теперь если картинки занакчиваются, слайдер не перемещается ) Ещё раз спасибо